# Bug? Problem with derivative of interpolating function from FEM

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, interpolation, finite-element-method, differentials

**Bug introduced in 10 or earlier and fixed in version 10.4**

---

I am really not sure if this is a bug or I am missing something very trivial.

**QUESTION: What I am missing in order to obtain the partial derivative of the interpolating function (in this case the fem solution)?**

**EDIT:** take a look at the comment by user21 directly underneath this question, the solution is to use `t` as the first variable.

**Context:**

I am testing the following pde with the Mathematica FEM

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(*Domain*)
xmin = 0;
xmax = 10;
reg = ImplicitRegion[xmin <= x <= xmax, {x}];
(*Field equation*)
sig[x_, t_] := Ef[x, t]*eps[x, t];
eps[x_, t_] := D[u[x, t], x];
feq = D[Af[x, t]*sig[x, t], x] + nf[x, t];
(*Paremeters*)
E0 = 3;
Ef[x_, t_] := E0;
A0 = 7;
Af[x_, t_] := A0;
sig0 = 2;
(*Inhomogeneity*)
nf[x_, t_] := 0;
F[t_] := A0*sig0*3*t;
(*Conditions*)
iconds = u[x, 0] == 0;
bconds = {DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 0, x == xmin]};
nconds = NeumannValue[-F[t], x == xmax];
(*Fem solution*)
ufem = NDSolveValue[{feq == nconds, iconds, bconds}, u, 
   Element[x, reg], {t, 0, 1}];
(*Plot*)
Plot[Table[ufem[x, ti], {ti, 0, 1, 0.2}], {x, xmin, xmax}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "u(x,t)"}]
```

[image: plot1]

From mechanics, the solution looks fine, it is linear in space $x$ and time $t$, just as it should be in this case. Just for fun I wanted to compute the spatial derivative of the solution. But I dont get a constant spatial derivative, as you can see in the plots below, e.g., for $t=0.2$.

```
Plot[ufem[x, 0.2], {x, xmin, xmax}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "ufem(x,0.2)"}]
loc = Derivative[1, 0][ufem];
Plot[loc[x, 0.2], {x, xmin, xmax}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "loc(x,0.2)"}]
```

[image: plot2]

From the `InterpolatingFunction` documentation, I assumed that partial derivates are computable, see screenshot below.

**QUESTION: What I am missing in order to obtain the partial derivative of the interpolating function (in this case the fem solution)?**

[image: ip_documentation]

Comment: It works if you use `t` as the first indepdent variable in your equations. This is a bug.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's kind of weird to have to use `t` as the first variable. But that is a weirdness I can live with :D Thanks!

Comment: This is now fixed in the sources and will be available with the next release after 10.3.1. In the meanwhile put the time variable in the first position.

Comment: @user21 For completeness: was it a bug in FEM or in `InterpolatingFunction`? Or both? Introduced in 10 or earlier?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, it was a bug in computing the derivative of an interpolating function when the time variable was last and the interpolating function is based on an element mesh. I did not check when it started.

Comment: This is fixed in version 10.4. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial derivatives **should** work on interpolation functions just fine, and I cannot see why your interpolating function should be any different.  But it is.  Here is a ridiculous workaround

```
ufem2 = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{{x, t}, ufem[x, t]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}, {t, 0, 
      1, .02}], 1]];
loc2 = Derivative[1, 0][ufem2];
Plot[{ufem[x, .2], loc2[x, 0.2]}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "loc(x,0.2)"}]
```

[image]

This seems like a bug to me, that you get completely the wrong derivative from the original interpolating function.

Comment: Yeah, it is really driving my nuts. I did not want to generate data from the fem solution, since I thought/assumed that the interpolating function from the fem conserves the elements order at their positions and the derivative reflects this information. Do you happen to know if this is true? For linear elements, piecewise constant derivative. Generating data and a sequential interpolation would kill this information, right?

Comment: What you say is true, the order of the arguments should be preserved, and reflected by the `Derivative` command.  Look at this code above, the "new" interpolating function `ufem2` should produce identical results to `ufem`, and take the same arguments in the same order.  But it behaves properly for the derivative, while `ufem` does not.

Comment: I understand the new interpolation, but assume that you have just 3 points in the fem with linear elements, i.e., the derivative in the first and second element would be constant. A sequential interpolation of these 3 points (assuming we keep this resolution) would give me a polynomial of second order and the derivate would be a line. I would only be able to get the "same" information by a sequential interpolation with higher resolution than the fem, right?

Comment: @MauricioLobos - not sure what you mean by 3 points - I sampled the same region that `ufem` is defined over, with $0\leq x \leq 10$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$, taking 50 data points along each coordinate.  So with 2500 data points to build an interpolating function on, you should be able to get decent derivatives.

Comment: To be clear I know **absolutely nothing** about finite element methods.  All I'm demonstrating here is that if you have an interpolating function that behaves well in that it gives values within its specified range, but misbehaves in that it won't give derivatives, you can build an identical interpolating function by taking all the values of the function on a rectangular grid - the resolution of this grid is up to you, your function `ufem` should give values for **any** number in its range

Comment: Ok :D I just mean hypothetically 3 points and supposed the function had a non-linear behavior in respect to $x$. I will ask this in a separate question. But thanks.

Comment: Right on, my thinking is that even if the underlying data was highly nonlinear, and had nonzero fourth derivatives (for example), if you use a tight enough mesh for the grid, then the interpolating function you get from it should be able to calculate them.  Look at the code I pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/gu5i3iVk) to see how accurate higher derivatives of interpolating functions can be